# How to get value from field widget during AJAX callback loop?

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

A select element on my form gets processed with an AJAX callback. There is a [Multiselect](http://drupal.org/project/multiselect) widget on the form, and I want to see the new value of the field as if the form had been submitted. But, the $form_state['values']['my_multiselect'] is always NULL when checked in the form builder function during AJAX callback. Where does Multiselect build the value from the form state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's an existing answer on Multiselect issue queue: [Changing multiselect options using #ajax](http://drupal.org/node/1124052#comment-5358914), and it has the solution.

Comment: Thanks, Johnathan. I thought I had just done that search but it was for Reply module issue queue.

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/585/call-to-action-flag-any-answer-that-is-not-an-answer